# Getting a handle on ActionItem on the ActionBar android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, handle, classcastexception

I want to get a handle on one of the menu items(I'm declaring this in XML).

```
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_shape_shifter"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:visible="true"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
```

So I do, 
      `MenuItem item_shape_shifter = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.menu_shape_shifter);`
 
      but it fails with an exception: ClassCastException: com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView  cannot be cast to android.view.MenuItem.

I cannot proceed without getting the handle on this menu item. But, can't find any leads.

Note: I am using the Action Bar Compatibility package since I'm supporting versions < 3.0

Comment: Are you trying to use Action Bar and supporting versions less than 3.0?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Compatibility package for that.

Answer (score 5):

You do not call `findViewById()` on a `View` to find an action bar item. You call `findItem()` on a `Menu` to find an action bar item.